# Strange characters when returning char array from struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, char

I am having some problems when returning with `printf` of a char array from a struct in C.

```
struct q_entry
{
    long mtype;
    char mtext[MAXLENGTH + 1];
};
```

The `long mtype` from the struct is returning fine, but the string is just returning some weird characters.

```
int proc_obj(struct q_entry *msg)
{
    printf("\npriority: %ld name: %s\n", msg->mtype, msg->mtext);
}
```

It just returns some strange characters like *"priority: 1 name: ▒▒(" and not "priority: 1 name: hello"*

I am populating the struct using the following code

```
int enter(char *objname, int priority)
{
    ...

    strncpy(s_entry.mtext, objname, sizeof(s_entry.mtext) - 1);
    s_entry.mtype = priority;

    // Send the message
    if (msgsnd(s_qid, &s_entry, len, 0) == -1)
    {
        printf("error: msgsnd failed\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(0);
    }
}
```

I don't have much experience with C, so I don't know too much about using structs. Please let me know if more context or parts of the code is needed. Any kind of help would be very helpful.

I have added a little more code in enter above, and here is more code of the when enter and proc_obj are called

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int priority;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("error: incorrect number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        priority = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    if (enter(argv[1], priority) < 0)
    {
        printf("error: message entering failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

This is in a different file from enter and above code

```
int server(void)
{
    int mlen, r_qid;
    struct q_entry r_entry;

    // Initialize queue
    if ((r_qid = init_queue()) == -1)
        return(-1);

    for (;;)
    {
        if ((mlen = msgrcv(r_qid, &r_entry, MAXLENGTH, (-1 * MAXPRIOR), MSG_NOERROR)) == -1)
        {
            printf("error: msgrcv failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            proc_obj(&r_entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to show the code where your enter() method is called

Comment: In fact, it would be helpful to show us a small, complete, compilable program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: So, I checked mlen, and it was 0. The return value of msgrcv "returns the number of bytes actually copied into the mtext array." So, I think that there is something wrong when I populate the struct. I am not sure, but is the value of the string not being passed and is being referenced, and when the server method tries to get the message from queue it is no longer able to reference the string?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion phoxis. Checking the size of len helped me figure out what was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer before adding more code*

It looks like the `s_entry` structure object is local, and `enter` works on the local variable. How are you calling `enter` and returning the structure after you have done initializing it ? note that you have `int` as the return type of the `enter` function. If you are doing `return s_entry;` then the output you are getting is possible, as only the first word of the structure, ie the lower `sizeof (int)` part of `mtype` is considered.

If you are using `enter` function like this as i described above then make the return type of `enter` to `struct s_entry`

---

You should check the size of `len` when sending the message.

Comment: The struct s_entry is being sent to a message queue after being populate using the following code `code` if (msgsnd(s_qid, &s_entry, len, 0) == -1) { printf("error: msgsnd failed\n"); return(-1); } `code` and then it is being received using `code` for (;;) { if ((mlen = msgrcv(r_qid, &r_entry, MAXLENGTH, (-1 * MAXPRIOR), MSG_NOERROR)) == -1) { printf("error: msgrcv failed\n"); exit(1); } else { proc_obj(&r_entry); } } `code`

Comment: you need to show us the `enter` call and the `proc_obj` call and where you have called `proc_obj` .

Comment: enter does not actually call proc_obj, it only sends the message to a message queue, and then another program called server retrieves the message and calls proc_obj

Comment: the high level details is nor required. We need to know the call line of the `enter` and the `proc_obj` , these can give us vital information. Please update the question with some more code.

Comment: can we get the message send function call line in the client ?

Answer (score 2):

The only obvious error in your code is that you should explicitly fill in a zero at `s_entry.mtext[MAXLENGTH]` such that the string will still be zero terminated if strncpy() hits the limit. But if that were the problem, you would see "hello" *followed by* strange characters. Are you sure that `objname` points to the text you're expecting it to point to?

Also, it looks a bit strange that proc_obj() is declared to return an int but actually does not return anything. Your compiler ought to complain about that.

Comment: Perhaps there's a return statement in the trailing "...".

Comment: @Keith Thompson `proc_obj()` doesn't have a trailing "..."; `enter()` does.

Comment: I have tried to fill in a zero at s_entry.mtext[MAXLENGTH] after seeing other posts, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. When I try to just return objname it does show the correct text. Would using msgsnd and msgrcv to send the message to a message queue and receive the message affect the output?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the message queue call but my guess is you are somehow miscalling the API and putting garbage into the queue (and then printing garbage in the server).

Comment: I don't think this is happening, since the long mtype is returning fine. I think it could be a more simple mistake with how the char is being passed or referenced or whatever that I just can't seem to figure out.